# Submit array elements in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a postage table with a rate column that is an array type using postgresql.
The array contains 3 values e.g [1.99, 2.99,5.99].
I can't figure out how to submit the form properly, I want to display a field for each element of the array.

my current non-working code is;

```
    = form_for [:admin,@postage] do |f|
      .field-box
        = f.label :name
        = f.text_field :name
        = f.label "UK"
        = text_field_tag "rate[]"
        = f.label 'EU'
        = text_field_tag "rate[]"
        = f.label "Rest of World"
        = text_field_tag "rate[]"
```

the form is passed in the parameters but isn't saved to the database

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx=", "postage"=>{"name"=>"Item1"}, "rate"=>["1.99","2.99","5.99"], "button"=>"", "id"=>"2"}
```

How do I correctly set up the form, and will the order always be intact?

Comment: are the values of the `rate` array supplied by the user and submitted in the form?

Comment: yes, they are inputs from the user

Comment: and is `rate` part of `@postage`?  ie, could you call `@postage.rate`?

Comment: Have you used `serialize :rate` in your model.

Comment: yes rate is a property of postage, there is no serialize as the rate column is of type 'array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is serializing properly. Are you using Rails 4? If so, check the permit method in your controller. For a PG array, it should look like this:

```
params.permit({rate: []})
```

Also, I would recommend changing the column name to rates. :)

Comment: I definitely haven't seen that permit implementation for PG arrays before, is it in the docs somewhere?

Comment: Not sure where it is in the docs, but we've been using this syntax without issue. Here's an article on it: http://theotherzach.com/writes/2013/3/11/rails-4-postgres-array-hstore-and-strong-params-guide-by-someone-that-likes-you

Comment: Did you try this syntax? Curious to see if it does the trick!

Comment: I scrapped using the PG array type a while ago but I can see 'unpermitted parameters' in the console from earlier which I somehow didn't see. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all I believe you still do need `serialize :rate` in your model class.
But to make that rate to match the format you showed in the beginning you need to do `rate = rate.map {|rt| rt.to_f}` (yea, I know there must be a way to simplify this).

Comment: serialize is not needed as the postgresql native array type is being used